# Why is my JPanel not showing up when called into JFrame?

Tags: java

Initially, I created my buttons and my JPanel in my GUI but I want to take them out of my GUI and create a different class for them since I have to add on to them.

Here is the following code that's giving me an issue.

The issue being that my JPanel isn't showing up. I extended the VButtons class to JPanel assuming that adding the JPanel to JFrame would work but no luck.

Any suggestions?

```
public static void vGui()  {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        B b;
        b = new B();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        frame.add(b, BorderLayout.WEST);
         frame.setVisible(true);
    }





     public static class B extends JPanel {

        B() {

              JPanel Panel1 = new JPanel();
              JRadioButton 1st button = new JRadioButton("1st button");
              JRadioButton 2nd button = new JRadioButton("2nd button");

              Panel1.add(1st button);
              Panel1.add(2nd button);
              Panel1.setLayout(new GridLayout(9,1))


   }




    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`VButtons extends JPanel`  <-- This itself is a JPanel

`JPanel Panel1` <-- But you are adding everything inside Panel1

And panel1 is just created and left unused.

So, remove Panel1.

Just call add method, because you are inside a subclass of JPanel.

You can call `this.add(...)` if that is clearer to read.

Comment: Just did it. Instead of doing panel1.add(button) I did this.add(button) and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the vertex from the left intersection to compile the right for  layout of the entire grid. The vertices won't intersect if you use 9,1. I like how you you used `removeVertex` but it is unnecessary.